How to show disc usage of all subfolders when parent and subfolders are owned by another user?
on my webserver i have a folder for my owncloud data.
this folder is owned by the www-data user.
i like to list all the subfolder disc-usage.
the total is possible by
du --summarize --human-readable --total /home/myuser/owncloud_data/
but i have not found a way yet to list the sizes of the subfolders themself.
i tried with
sudo du --summarize --human-readable --total /home/myuser/owncloud_data/*/
but that gives me a file not found error:
du: Zugriff auf '/home/myuser/owncloud_data/*/' nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
for now i changed the owner to my user and left only the group as www-data. this works.
but out of curiosity - how would it work without the owner change?

Is the folder in question a mount point of some sort? A network filesystem or FUSE or something else?

no it is a normal folder

What if you run sudo du -d 1 --human-readable --total /home/myuser/owncloud_data/?

@muru yeah that is working :-) i changed it to the easier readable version sudo du --max-depth=1 --human-readable --total /home/myuser/owncloud_data/ 

You need to get super-user rights by using sudo.
Like sudo du --summarize --human-readable --total /home/myuser/owncloud_data/
It will ask for your password, that is your own password, not root's or ything else.

i missed the sudo in coping in here. sorry.. did you tried it?
for me that did not work. i think that somehow the bash commandline expansion does not return the content of the folder as it would need to do this in sudo-space... and it seams this happens to early ?!
